# getting correct type and format out of a jQuery.map() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jquery, types

I hard coded the following array and I can use it to insert selections into an Autocomplete dropdown. It seems to be an array of JSON objects, though I am a JS novice and could be wrong. It works.

```
var boroughData = [
    {"label":"New York, Bronx, Bronx County, New York, United States","value":"Bronx, Bronx County, New York, United States"},
    {"label":"New York, Staten Island, Richmond County, New York, United States","value":"Staten Island, Richmond County, New York, United States"}
];
```

I want to provide similar data from a database and assemble it via a .map() function. I have something working, but the output is a different format/type. It seems to be an array with one long string, though again, I could be wrong. An example (with different cities) is below. Note the initial and ending " that is not in my hard coded array above.

```
["{"label":"Dallas, Cockr... Texas, United States"}", "{"label":"Dallas, Downt... Texas, United States"}", "{"label":"Dallas, East ... Texas, United States"}"]
```

The data from the database currently looks like the following, though it could be changed, if that helps.

```
{"label":"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, Dallas County, Texas, United States", "value":"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, Dallas County, Texas, United States"}
```

I tried string manipulation to replace/remove the initial and ending " but I could not get it to work. Maybe I need something different in the .map() function to create objects.  My .map() in an ajax success option is as follows

```
success: function (data){
    boroughData = $.map( data, function (item){
        return item.boroughString;
        //returning {"label":"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, Dallas County, Texas, United States", "value":"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, Dallas County, Texas, United States"}
    });
    alert(jQuery.isArray(boroughData)  + "|bD1"); //true, is array
    return boroughData;
}
```

How do I get a return result that is the same type/format as my hard coded array? Please be specific with code. I don't follow general instructions well.

Comment: No, they're just plain objects. Call them "literals" if you want. JSON is the string serialisation.

Comment: Um, yes, that output with the quotes is invalid (you'd at least need to escape the other quotes in the string). How did you get that? The data in the database looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data that you get in `item.boroughString` is a string, you probably can parse it with `JSON.parse` (or use `json2.js` for browsers who don't support this functionality - see also this question : [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)) and it should convert you this string in a full JSON object.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data){
        boroughData = $.map( data, function (item){
            return JSON.parse(item.boroughString);
            // should return JSON object {"label":"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, Dallas County, Texas, United States", "value":"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, Dallas County, Texas, United States"}
        });

        alert(jQuery.isArray(boroughData)  + "|bD1"); //true, it is again an array

        //return boroughData; Your success should not return a variable to be used after!!! Ajax is asynchronous
        //
        // Rather use a callback function
        functionToBeExecutedAfterTheSuccess();
    }
});

function functionToBeExecutedAfterTheSuccess() {
    alert(boroughData + "|bD3"); //[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] with OK contents
}
```

Comment: Samuel, progress, and in fact you may have fixed the problem as I originally posted the code. But I found that the function surrounding the code is part of the problem. I have edited the code to add the entire function - and it should show up after review. Note that isArray is true before the return statement, and 2 lines later, after the return, it is false. I tried declaring boroughData as an array and then executing the function, but it did not work. Your code is progress because when I enter a city a second time, it works. Now to get it on the first entry.

Comment: You are mixing different affectations for the same object here! with the 1st line (BTW, you should have edited your own post, since I will probably edit my post and loosing your edit...), you assign a function to the variable `boroughData`. And with the ajax call, you overwrite it with the returning data! And becareful : `$.ajax` is asynchronous, then you should not use variables createdin it after the ajax call! I will edit my post with a working way.

Comment: Samuel, stackoverflow has still not reviewed and released my code edits (2:30PM EST) so its pretty tough for you and any other contributors. Nonetheless, I removed the return boroughData - without any noticeable effect. When the 2 alerts after the ajax are there, the code inserts new data from the database on the second data entry. When those alerts are commented out, no insert to the Autocomplete dropdown occurs. Pretty strange.

Comment: I get a console.log after the isArray alert in the .map().  Here's what boroughData looks like at that point.    [Object { label=

"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, ...y, Texas, United States"

,  value=

"Dallas, Cockrell Hill, ...y, Texas, United States"

}, Object { label=

"Dallas, Downtown Dallas...y, Texas, United States"

,  value=

"Dallas, Downtown Dallas...y, Texas, United States"

}, Object { label=

"Dallas, East Dallas, Da...y, Texas, United States"

,  value=

"Dallas, East Dallas, Da...y, Texas, United States"

}]

Comment: The function surrounding that ajax does something to the array format because the very next line is an isArray alert and it returns false. There's the remaining problem. I don't know the solution.

Comment: In fact, an ajax does not return any values (except from a `$.Deferred` - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and then you can not use it in the normal flow. You can read [MDN ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=AJAX%3AGetting_Started) about this. The way to use ajax is to call a server action which will return either an error or a success with some data. Thus an ajax call is send but we don't know when it will finished and I suspect that in your example it finishes between the 2 `console.log`!

Comment: Samuel, you fixed the part of the problem that was visible in the code I originally posted, so I am clicking it as the accepted solution. Thank you. I will post most of this again, plus the function statements, tomorrow and try to get some help on the change in format that occurs to the array. I hear you on the asynchronous stuff, but it is format change that seems to be the remaining problem.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the best thing you can do is to make sure the server returns a valid JSON object. It is usually not recommended to fix something in Javascript that can be fixed server side.

That said, the way to transform the string into the array that is equal to the hard coded array, you can use this:

```
success: function (data){
    // split the data with separator ", 
    var parts = data.split("\",");
    var boroughData = [];
    // looping through all parts
    for (var i=0, ii=parts.length; i < ii; i++) {
      // getting the value of the part between { and }
      var part = parts[i].substring(parts[i].indexOf("{"),parts[i].indexOf("}")+1);
      // add part as json to the array
      boroughData.push($.parseJSON(part));
    }
    return boroughData;
}
```

Comment: Walter, when I remove curly brackets {} from around the text in the database row, I get valid JSON returned. In that case, the second isArray test is false, and the alert(boroughData + "|bD3") is undefined. Plus Autocomplete stops functioning completely. I found the curly brackets moved me in the right direction, though not to a full solution. I will try the code you posted. If you have code that works with a JSON server return, I agree, that would be cleaner. I'm just trying to get something that works.

Comment: Walter, I tried your code. Part of the problem was in the success: option, and it turns out part is in the way I wrote a function. I'm sorry I didn't post all at first, but I didn't realize a function problem exists - and still does - I don't understand it. I hope stackoverflow soon completes their review of my code edit and shows my expanded code. FWIW, with your code the second isArray test outside the function is false, and the boroughData variable is undefined. You went to a lot of work on the part expression. Sorry I had not showed the full function.

Comment: Hi Mike, no worries. I assumed the data variable contained the example data (as a string). And in that case, my code seems to work. I will check your code later when stackoverflow reviewed your code.